# Converting a list of dynamic obects to a Dictionary<propertyName, Values>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to convert a `List<object>` containing dynamic objects to a dictionary where the key is the propertyname and the value is the distinct values for that property.

Currently I used this piece of code, but I feel there must be a more elegant/faster way to do this?

```
var records = ((IEnumerable)enumerable).Cast<object>().ToList();
var result = new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>();
foreach (object record in records)
{
    foreach (var propertyName in properties)
    {
        var colValue = record.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(record, null);

        if (colValue != null)
        {
            if (result.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            {
                result[propertyName].Add(colValue.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(propertyName, new List<string>() { colValue.ToString() });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you approch the probelm is good but you need some changes that will make the method much faster.

```
private static Dictionary <Type, List <PropertyInfo>> Props = new Dictionary<Type, List<PropertyInfo>> (); 
public Dictionary <string,IList<String>> Convert(List <object> records) {                                  
    var result = new Dictionary <string,IList <string>>();                                                 
    foreach(object record in records) {                                                                    
        if (!Props.ContainsKey(record.GetType()))                                                          
            Props.Add(record.GetType(), record.GetType().GetProperties());                                 

        foreach(var prop in Props[record.GetType()]) {                                                     
            var colValue = prop.GetValue(record, null);                                                    
            if (colValue != null) {                                                                        
                if (result.ContainsKey(prop.Name)) {                                                       
                    result[prop.Name].Add(colValue.ToString());                                            
                }                                                                                          
                else {                                                                                     
                    result.Add(prop.Name, new List <string> () {colValue.ToString()});                     
                }                                                                                          
            }                                                                                              
        }                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                      
    return result;                                                                                         
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer, have a look

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var result = properties.ToDictionary(
    keySelector: propertyName => propertyName,
    elementSelector: propertyName => records
          .Select(record => record.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)?.GetValue(record, null).ToString())
          .Where(colValue => colValue != null));
```